# Sharing some code in every resource in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I would like to always hide "view" screen in active admin.

```
controller do
  def create
    super do |format|
      redirect_to collection_url and return if resource.valid?
    end
  end

  def update
    super do |format|
      redirect_to collection_url and return if resource.valid?
    end
  end

  def show
    redirect_to edit_resource_path(resource)
  end
end
```

I would like this code to be executed on every resource - without copy/pasting. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the `show` action at all, you can solve your problem by disabling the `show` action:

```
actions :all, except: [:show]
```